# Homotopy in extended complex plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let F be a polynomial defined from complex plane to itself.Then F extended to a polynomial in  (C u {infinity}). Show that F and -F are homotopic in extended complex plane.

My Idea :  F and -F are homotopic in C by line homotopy(say H) i.e 
H(z,t)=(1-t)F + t.(-F).
If we can show that H fixes infinity for all t then we can extend H. But for t=1/2  H sends infinity to zero.So I got stuck there.
So I need some help.

Comment: Are you familiar with thinking of $\mathbb{C} \cup \infty$ as the Riemann sphere?  If so, think about the map $z \mapsto -z$ geometrically on the sphere.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with that  but how to show that antipodal map and identity map are homotopic in sphere?

Comment: The map $z \mapsto -z$ is not the antipodal map (think about what happens to $0$ and to $\infty$ for example).  In fact the identity and antipodal maps are not homotopic; this is usually proved in a first course on homology.

Comment: Sorry, I know that z -> -z is the antipodal map in sphere. In S^2  antipodal map and identity map are not homotopic due to their different degree.

Comment: $p \mapsto -p$ is the antipodal map of a sphere when you have the sphere $S^n$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. But the map $z \mapsto -z$ of the complex plane, or its extension to the Riemann sphere does not correspond to the antipodal map of $S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thanks.Now its clear to me. But still I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: What about $e^{i\pi t}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say..
e^(i. pi.t) is a point on the circle.

Comment: $z \mapsto -z$ represents a rotation through angle $\pi$ about the axis through $0$ and $\infty$.  In general, multiplication by $e^{i \theta}$, in other words $z \mapsto e^{i \theta} z$, represents rotation through angle $\theta$ about this axis.  Now can you see what to do?

Comment: Yes..I understand. Thank you...